# Сохранять состояние страницы(фрагмента)

Tags: android, kotlin

Есть список элементов, по клику на какой то из них, перехожу в конкретный фрагмент, но при нажатии назад возвращает не совсем на ту страницу(а на последний/активный *месяц*) тут **поясню**, есть несколько страниц разбитых по месяцам(в которых разные списки с элементами по которым я кликаю).

Как перед тем как нажать на элемент трэкать состояние страницы(фрагмента) с которой я совершаю клик ? На англисйском это звучит лучше) *The pager should keep track of the page that was active before entering transaction list*.

Для этих целей на данный момент использую этот метод

```
fun Activity?.addFragment(fragment: Fragment?) {
    if (this == null || fragment == null) return
    try {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment, fragment.createTagName())
                .addToBackStack(null).commit()
    } catch (ignored: IllegalStateException) {
    }
}
```

но как трэкать(**сохранять страницу**) предыдущий фрагмент думаю нужно до вызова данного метода.

Comment: Возможно стоит попробовать повесить что то типо `currentPageIndex` во фрагмент из которого кликаете по элементу  и потом проверять какой индекс у этой страницы. 
Если бы у вас было бы что то типо ввода текста во вьюшки, тогда да, имело бы смысл сохранять состояние фрагмента, а так думаю мимо.

Comment: @Morozov а можно какой нибудь пример, а то если честно немного затрудняюсь.